# How do we solve for x using Euler Identity in $\tan(2x) = -1$?

Tags: trigonometry

> Solve for $x$ using Euler Identity.
>
> $$\tan(2x) = -1$$

We can first note that

$$\tan(2x) = \dfrac{\sin(2x)}{\cos(2x)} = \dfrac{e^{2ix}-e^{-2ix}}{i(e^{2ix}+e^{-2ix})} = -1$$

$$e^{2ix}- e^{-2ix}+i(e^{2ix}+e^{-2ix}) = 0$$

Let $w = e^{2ix}$

$$w-w^{-1} +i(w+w^{-1}) = 0$$

$$w^2 -1+i(w^2+1) = 0$$

This is where I'm stuck.

Comment: That is simply an ordinary quadratic equation,

$$(1+i)w^2 -i+1=0.$$

Do you know how to solve quadratic equations with complex coefficients?

Comment: @LukeCollins No, unfortunalety.

Comment: In this case, it's simply $$w^2 = -\frac{1-i}{1+i}=i,$$ so you need to find $w=a+bi$ such that $(a+bi)^2 = i$. Comparing real and imaginary parts should give you the possibilities for $a$ and $b$.

Comment: It is a *very special* quadratic equation (only $w^2$, no $w$). Alternatively, let $w=e^{4ix}$.

Comment: Solving quadratic equations is done in exactly the same way over any (non characteristic-2) field: the quadratic formula. The equation $aw^2 + bw + c = 0$ has solutions $w = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$. Doesn't matter whether $a, b, c$ are rational numbers, real numbers, complex numbers, integers modulo $5$ or $3$-adic numbers. The same formula applies (although the way you calculate the square root and the fraction changes from field to field).

Answer (score 1):

Note that$$w^2-1+i(w^2+1)=0\iff w^2=-i.$$So, take the square roots of $-i$, which are $\pm\left(-\frac1{\sqrt2}+\frac i{\sqrt2}\right)$.

Comment: $w^2 = 1$ also holds.

Comment: Are you claming that $1-1+i(1+1)=0$?

Comment: Oh, it does not make sense now. However, real part should also be $0$.

Comment: @enzo it is. Just that both the terms (with and without $i$) are complex numbers, not reals.

Comment: Because $w=e^{2ix}$ is not real

Comment: I see now, thanks.

Comment: $w^2 = -1$ gives $e^{4ix} = -1$, since $e^{\pi i} = -1$, $x = \dfrac{\pi}{4}$ but this is not the correct solution.

Comment: $w^2=-i$ gives $e^{8ix}=-1$ with a possible solution $x=-\frac{\pi}8$